# How to open a template in Django platform

Tags: python, django

I want to open a html file i.e map.html which is saved in same directories where i saved this views.py and urls.py. (django based platform)

I wrote this sample code for views.py (to load map.html) but it is not working:

```
 from django.template import Template, Context,RequestContext 
 from django.http import HttpResponse
 import datetime

 def router_map(request):
     fp = open('./map.html')
     t = Template(fp.read())
     fp.close()
     html = t.render(Context({'router_map'}))
     return HttpResponse(html)
```

and my urls.py is:

```
 from django.conf.urls.defaults import * 
 from umit.views import router_map

 urlpatterns = patterns('',
     (r'^index/$', router_map),
 )
```

Comment: Can't you add the directory to the `TEMPLATE_DIRS` in settings.py? Then you don't need to open the template manually.

Comment: I don't want to do that. would you please tell me.to how to do by manually

Comment: Then I have to ask, what is not working? Do you get errors? Is the template not rendered properly? What happens?

Comment: I am new at Django.Would you please give me a code to do that or is something is wrong with this code?

Comment: Please explain why you think you need to open it manually.

Comment: when posting python code please take care for preserving indention. or better: always preserve it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, I think, that you are using the path `'./map.html'`. This is means that Python will try and find the current directory of the *program*, not the same directory as the view file is in.

Lets say the Django project is in the directory `/home/foo/myproject`. If you `cd` to that directory and run `python manager.py runserver`, the current directory inside the application (i.e. the directory `.`) will be `/home/foo/myproject`, which is not what you want.

The easiest way to fix this is to use the full path to the file in your call to `open`:

```
fp = open('/home/foo/myproject/myapp/views/map.html')
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did that .Now it is showing this error:
Caught VariableDoesNotExist while rendering: Failed lookup for key [null] in u"[set(['final'])]"

Comment: Would you please help me...Please give me a sample code fo just to imbed a html file or when i open localhost/index then it will open that html file

Comment: @komal Your last error might be something wrong with the template. I can't help you as I don't have Django at work and cant test anything. And I really urge you to put templates in the standard location for Django, so you don't have to open them manually.